# python logging: print accurrate info from custom log level

Tags: python, logging

I created a custom log level as below:

```
class MyLoggerAdapter(logging.LoggerAdapter):
    def __init__(self, logger, extra):
        logging.LoggerAdapter.__init__(self, logger, extra)
        self.logger = logger
        logging.addLevelName(25, "NOTICE")

    def notice(self, msg, *args, **kwargs):
        self.logger.log(25, msg, *args, **kwargs)
```

The issue I have is that my logger format uses `%(pathname)s` and `%(lineno)d`, and whenever I call `logger.notice()` those values refer to the line within the definition of the notice method, rather than the location that the method was called from.  How do I add the `notice` log level but print the correct location of the message to the logs?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12980512/custom-logger-class-and-correct-line-number-function-name-in-log asks about something similar but for writing a custom handler - are any of the suggestions there useful? Alternatively, http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/python/python/1190721 suggests ways of adding new log levels without creating a new LoggerAdapter class, and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2183233/how-to-add-a-custom-loglevel-to-pythons-logging-facility has answers going into more detail about adding custom loglevels.

Comment: @bouteillebleu is it possible to do what I want in a subclass?