# Adding an extension to a logger name

Tags: python, logging

I've created a wrapper for the logger for my app

```
import logging

class myLogger:
    def __init__(self, name):
        # levels = (logging.DEBUG, logging.INFO, logging.WARNING, logging.ERROR, logging.CRITICAL)
        logging.basicConfig(
            level = logging.DEBUG,
            format = '%(asctime)s %(name)-12s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s',
            datefmt = '%m-%d %H:%M',
            filename = '/tmp/myLog.log',
            filemode = 'a'
            )

        self.logger = logging.getLogger(name)
        self.name = name

    def formatString(self, msg, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Capitalizes the first letter of a string
        """
        return msg[0].upper() + msg[1:]

    def debug(self, msg=''):
        """
        Wrapper for logger.debug method. Formats the debug message to ensure it writes
        to the log file.
        """
        if not msg:
            raise(ValueError("DEBUG message cannot be blank!"))

        if not msg[0].isupper():
            msg = self.formatString(msg)

        self.logger.debug(msg)

    def info(self, msg=''):
        """
        Wrapper for logger.info method. Formats the debug message to ensure it writes
        to the log file.
        """
        if not msg:
            raise(ValueError("INFO message cannot be blank!"))

        if not msg[0].isupper():
            msg = self.formatString(msg)

        self.logger.info(msg)

    def warning(self, msg=''):
        """
        Wrapper for logger.warning method. Formats the debug message to ensure it writes
        to the log file.
        """
        if not msg:
            raise(ValueError("WARNING message cannot be blank!"))

        if not msg[0].isupper():
            msg = self.formatString(msg)

        self.logger.warning(msg)

    def error(self, msg=''):
        """
        Wrapper for logger.error method. Formats the debug message to ensure it writes
        to the log file.
        """
        if not msg:
            raise(ValueError("ERROR message cannot be blank!"))
        if not msg[0].isupper():
            msg = self.formatString(msg)

        self.logger.error(msg)

    def critical(self, msg=''):
        """
        Wrapper for logger.critical method. Formats the debug message to ensure it writes
        to the log file.
        """
        if not msg:
            raise(ValueError("CRITICAL message cannot be blank!"))

        if not msg[0].isupper():
            msg = self.formatString(msg)

        self.logger.critical(msg)

    def getLogger(self, name):
        self.logger = logging.getLogger("{}.{}".format(self.logger.name, name))
```

and I'd like to be able to pass the logger from class to class while updating the logger name to fit where it is being used. However, right now the logger name is updating globally for everywhere the logger is used. What I'd like to have happen is:

I'm passing the logger from the main instantiation to the sub classes with

```
def __init__(self, logger):
```

and I'd like each pass of the logger to use a different logger name dependent on where in the program the logger is being used. However, right now the logger name is appending for every instance of the logger.

Can you please help me figure out how to pass the logger between classes and update the logger name?

For clarification, I have the following setup:

```
         - subfolder 1/sub1.py
main.py
         - subfolder 2/sub2.py
```

I'd like the same logger to write to the same log file. It should write to the log file such that

```
main.py: 09-05 18:19 main       ERROR    Error logged: Error message

sub1.py: 09-05 18:19 main.subfolder1.sub1       ERROR    Error logged: Error message

sub2.py: 09-05 18:19 main.subfolder2.sub2       ERROR    Error logged: Error message
```

Comment: What do you mean by update the logger name? Do you want it to write to different log files? That wouldn't be the same logger.

Comment: Please see the update I made to my question for clarification. I would like the logger to write to the same log file with the location in the app and class that the logger is in.

Comment: Can you pass that in the "extra" parameter? They sound like custom variables that you'd include in the format string and pass as the "extra" dict.

Comment: What you've done in your custom class might be achieved with https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.LoggerAdapter

Comment: Why not use child loggers for that? You don't normally pass around logger objects, you just create one in each module. ["Child loggers propagate messages up to the handlers associated with their ancestor loggers. Because of this, it is unnecessary to define and configure handlers for all the loggers an application uses. It is sufficient to configure handlers for a top-level logger and create child loggers as needed."](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#loggers)

Comment: This has some good discussion on how to embed info on where in the code a log message originated: https://stackoverflow.com/q/12980512/1766544

Comment: What you are doing is an anti-pattern. logging configuration (e.g. via `basicConfig()`) should only ever be done in an `if __name__ == '__main__':` clause or a `main()` function, and not from a class initializer or function that might be called multiple times (as in your example).